# What do you call the thing that allows the drill to rotate in a power drill?

Tags: word-request

[image: https://i.insider.com/5ecd76713ad86143487d1ff9?width=1136&format=jpeg]

And is the component a generic component to other machines or tools that allows something to rotate, or is this only specific to a power drill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the motor that causes the rotation, and it is bearings that support the part that will rotate. In general, motors make things move, while bearings are surfaces where parts "bear" on each other (that is, they slide over each other. Bearings are designed to allow that sliding without much wear, and to confine the movement.

Answer (score 1):

A **motor** is:

> a rotating machine that transforms electrical energy into mechanical energy
> — [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motor)

It's a very widely understood word, and also the term used by professionals. Motors are found in a lot of other machines, such as cars.

Here's a drill-related example of the word:

> Cordless drill motors are based off one of the earliest designs for motors; that is the brushed DC motor. The magnet-based motor requires direct voltage to make the motor work. Normally, this requires a plug that would render drill "corded." With the invention of rechargeable batteries though, removable battery packs have enabled the drill to be cordless.
> — [What Kind of Motor Is in a Cordless Drill?](https://www.hunker.com/13407403/what-kind-of-motor-is-in-a-cordless-drill)