# What do you call the thing that allows the thing that holds the drill to rotate in a power drill?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the thing that allows the thing that holds the drill to rotate? I understand that the motor powers the drill, but I would like to know what allows it to rotate in the first place. I am thinking this thing is a generic object that exists in other tools and machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that **holds** the drill is called the *chuck*.

[Wikipedia drill chuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_(engineering)#Drill_chuck)

Comment: What allows the chuck to rotate?

Comment: @Sayaman, [as Jack answered](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/283157/130147) on your other question, the drill contains [**bearings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(mechanical))  that hold the chuck in place vertically while allowing it to rotate about its axis.